# When Fragment displays you can see the host Activity behind it (as if it is transparent)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an Activity which contains a button. When this button is pressed, I want a certain Fragment to be displayed. However, what is currently happen is the Fragment gets displayed but you can still see the host Activity behind it - and I'm not sure why.

This is how I'm doing it - host Activity:

```
continueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.continueButton) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = new RegisterPassword();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        }
    });
```

and the Fragment I'm using is:

```
public class RegisterPassword extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register_password, container, false);
}
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I suspect it's something to do with

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
```

I'm not sure if it's replacing the right layout - or is android.R.id.content generic, representing your current activity/fragment?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit:

host Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Register">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick A Username"
        android:textColor="#3f9845"
        android:textSize="29dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This will be the name that appears on your profile"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#3f9845"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continueButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textColor="#3f9845"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sv_laptop03.snapchain.RegisterPassword">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your fragment xml as well please

Comment: Posted both - check edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the fragment is always loaded on top. You can add a background to it and also (important!) make it clickable so that you don't press anything in the activity in the background:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@color/white"

    tools:context="com.example.sv_laptop03.snapchain.RegisterPassword">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your fragment layout is without a background. Set a background color/resource as:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    ...
```